# Azure ARM - combine tags passed as parameters with literal tags

Tags: azure, tags

I have several ARM templates, all receive list of tags as an object type parameter:

```
"tagValues": {
    "type": "object"
}
```

In "resources" section I refer to tagValues as follows:

```
"tags": "[parameters('tagValues')]"
```

This approach works fine for all ARM templates except the one for creating Azure Functions App, because ARM template definition already contains a 'hidden-link:' tag:

```
"tags": {
    "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('appServices')[copyIndex()].name)]": "Resource"
}
```

Is there a way to union/combine tags passed into tagValues parameter with this 'hidden-link:' tag? I cannot move 'hidden-link:' tag into a variable, because it is in a copy loop.

Comment: [This answer to another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51392382/arm-template-concatenate-objects) may help you out. 

Comment: Thanks, it works. You can post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARM templates have a `union` function, which is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-array#union).

There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51392382/arm-template-concatenate-objects) which looks like it can help you out too